# Onclick function is not blocking the HREF value of anchor tag  on returning true 

Tags: javascript, html

I found that onclick function must return false for proceeding with href value and true for blocking the same . I used the same here too . on returning false , it is right , proceeding with URL but on returning true , it is also opening the URL page .

So what is different between returning true / false value from onclick function .

I am using Firefox 9.0.1 and IE 7 . . Following is my html file .

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function clickthis()
 {
 alert("its onclick Function call ");
 return true;
 }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body >
  <a id="foo" onclick="clickthis();" href="http://google.com">google</a>
 </body>
</html>
```

I got confused with this behaviour .

Comment: your onclick should read `onclick="return clickthis();"`, but @Lolo has the right solution

Comment: Look into a JavaScript library like jQuery, so you can attach events instead of hard-coding them. It's easier to maintain, and more accessible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event handler needs to return `false` to prevent normal link action, and it is not suffient to just call a function; the handler itself needs to return the value `false` if you wish to suppress the action. So the attribute should be

```
onclick="return clickthis();"
```

Comment: Thanks It's working.But could you please tell that function itself is returning value(lets say false).So calling function means it is returning so  why it must place  "return clickthis() "in onclick attribute . (I checked too without placing 'return' there it is not blocking ) .  Well thanks for this wonderful answer . It gets me to know how html proceesing is done .

Comment: Think of the contents of an `onclick="..."` attribute as the body of an anonymous function. If you have just the call `clickthis()`, then the value returned by the function is ignored. The caller itself, the “anonymous function body,” needs to return the desired value to affect the way the browser handles the clicking of the link.

Comment: Thanks for this Indepth knowledge . This community really ROCKS :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should use `preventDefault` method on event object.
Example: http://jsfiddle.net/lolo/vD5hK/

Comment: I have one question . Why Alert is not called which is at HREF of tag ? It should also be called .

Comment: Because `preventDefault` is called in `onclick` handler. Onclick goes before href, and because event is blocked by `preventDefault` it not bubbles to href. If you comment out `e.preventHandler()` call it'll execute alert from href.

Answer (score 1):

*[TESTED with Firefox 35.0.1]*

I made some solution for it.
In case of anchor detected, with href defined, the click take over and redirect the page.

code:

```
<html><title></title><body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function clickthis(e, obj)
{
console.log('click');
    e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({url: "a.html", 
        success: function(result){
            console.log('ajax success');
            makeRedirect(obj);
        },
        error: function(result){        
            console.log('ajax error');
            makeRedirect(obj);
        }       
    });
}
function makeRedirect(obj){
    if (obj && obj.tagName == 'A' && obj.href){
        console.log('redirecting');
        window.location = obj.href;
    }
}
</script>

<a id="foo" onclick="clickthis(event,this);" href="http://www.google.com">###3 google 3###</a>
</body></html>
```

note:
u can even make the redirect once all your asynchronous logic finished...

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `onclick="return clickthis();"` and clickthis() has to return false.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for progressive enhancement (i.e. going to google.com if the user doesn't have javascript enabled, showing the alert if they do), then you want your markup to look like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function clickthis(e)
 {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert("its onlcick Function call ");
    return false;
 }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body >
  <a id="foo" onclick="clickthis(event);" href="http://google.com">google</a>
 </body>
</html>
```